# PHP getallheaders() will automatically send a response if i try to get a non existent key

Tags: php, http-headers

I tried to use the function getallheaders() in php which basically gets the headers of the request as an associative array. the strange thing is that when i try to get a variable from this array if the key does not exist in this array it will send a response to the user.
Here's the sample Code

```
$headers = getallheaders();
$a = $headers["non_existing_key"];
echo headers_sent();
```

This will print 1 which means that headers were sent, or in other words i can no longer open a session for the user because session_start() will work only if headers were not sent yet.
i know that i can check the key with isset(), but this is just of curiosity.
Can someone help me why this is happening?.

Comment: pretty sure that the array won't send any headers back

Comment: Do you mean it's throwing a notice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have enabled `error_reporting` and `display_errors` your code will trigger:

> Notice: Undefined index: non_existing_key

In order to display the error PHP needs to send output to browser because you can't mix HTTP headers and output.

You can verify if a key exists with the usual techniques (pick your favourite):

```
$a = isset($headers["non_existing_key"]) ? $headers["non_existing_key"] : null;
$a = array_key_exists("non_existing_key", $headers) ? $headers["non_existing_key"] : null;
$a = $headers["non_existing_key"] ?? null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn on output buffering

This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer.

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php